# Better polarization for push-pull

Tags: bjt, load

I have a circuit that used to drive a lighter load.

I need to increase the current it manages to drive (and mainly the turn off time).

In the following schematic I show what I want to do: the old circuit had everything but D1, D2, Q3, R5, that I'm planning to add.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpuSsc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I feel this solution is still far from the best.

Hope someone can tell me a better solution that I can implement just by adding few components to the initial circuit.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you simulated this? What load are you wanting to drive that makes the old circuit problematic?

Comment: @Andyaka I did simulate the circuit and it performs quite well. The 1uF load is realistic for my application, before the circuit used to drive 47nF and had a 10k resistor, instead of Q3, to discharge the capacitor.

Comment: +1 for using CircuitLab